# Cannot see changes made to aspx

Tags: jquery, caching, asp.net

I'm trying to edit an aspx page...mainly javascript, and I randomly see changes that I've made when refreshing.

I'm using jquery, but I'm not sure that jquery is the culprit here.

For example.  If I add a simple alert("hello"); in the page I'm calling, I do not see it take place until I have cleared all my temp files and cache, closed my browser opened back up...and even then, sometimes, I still don't see my changes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Never did figure out what this was.  Moved away from ASP and redid in PHP.  Works like a champ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to force a full refresh, this will make your scripts reload.  IE likes to hold onto things...usually in a way that doesn't make any sense of obey any rules.

Alternatively, set no cache on the server, like this:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

Or in the head of the page html, like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
```

Comment: it doesn't.  I've tried.  It is the strangest thing.  I added a simple "hello" in the body tag and that doesn't even show up.  And yes....I am editing the right file and opening up the right file in my browser.

Comment: @Senica - You have cache headers being set correctly from the server, or a `<meta>` tag in the page?

Comment: Do you have any cache-control directives in the HTTP Headers for scripts or image files?

Comment: I went ahead and added the meta tag for no cache in my head.  Still not working.  Even a simple edit like adding test to the page does not show up.  I think perhaps a server issue of some sort...?

Comment: @Senica - Can you confirm with fiddler or Firefox/firebug that it is indeed a cache issue on the client? perhaps you have output caching turned on?

Answer (score 0):

you can do several things that will help you to find the issue

1. Using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) Check for any JavaScript errors
2. To be sure of using the same file hit Ctrl + A to select all and then hit Del, save the file and check if page is empty.
3. Hit Ctrl + F5 to refresh browsers cache
4. Dont use alert("something") to debug, you can use a debugger; line with [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/).